# How to prevent ViewData content encoding in ASP.Net Core Razor?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is fragment from View file:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "qwerty **Николай**";
}
<div class="row">
<div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
    <div class="large-12 cell">
        <h1>Николай Петюх</h1>
    </div>        
</div>
```

And this is output fragment in browser:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>qwerty **&#x41D;&#x438;&#x43A;&#x43E;&#x43B;&#x430;&#x439;**</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/foundation/css/foundation.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css?v=drh6roXOzy8LX0aJC9iKPBtj4DtYf06wh1r9I6IvZA0" />


</head>
<body>

<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
            <div class="large-12 cell">
                <h1>Николай Петюх</h1>
            </div>        
        </div>    
    </div>    
</div>
```

Anybody knows how to prevent cyrillic characters encoding to &#XXXX;?

Comment: I copied your code from the question and tested . Razor renders `<title>qwerty **Николай**</title>` to me

Comment: Interesting. Do you know, where is Razor settings. Sorry for stupid question, but im newbie

Comment: Found solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Resolve problem by adding to **Startup.cs** next code:

```
services.Configure<WebEncoderOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.TextEncoderSettings = new TextEncoderSettings(UnicodeRanges.All);
            });
```

in **ConfigureServices** class.